# Is it possible to ignore dialogue boxes when checking size of focused window?

Tags: python, windows, focus

I noticed that if using windows focus detection, the `rect` value will change depending on what part of the program you are in. I want the size of the main window only if possible.

I've managed to get around some of these issues by checking the window title. If the title is empty, it's a dropdown menu, so ignore. If it is titled "Open", "Save As", etc, then it's obviously a dialogue box and ignore. However, the message "Do you want to quit without saving?" seems to have only the title of the program itself, so that slips through the check.

I just tested the heights of those boxes to see if there was a constant value to ignore, but each program seems to have different heights. I could possibly just ignore anything under a certain resolution, but I'd prefer not to as it's not actually solving the issue, and there may be some rare cases where it needs to use that particular resolution.

Here's the bits of code I currently use from `pywin32` to do the detection. I also have the ctypes alternatives, but it's basically the same thing.

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import psutil

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

print 'pid:', win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)[1]
print 'rect:', win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
print 'name:', win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
print 'exe:', psutil.Process(win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)[1]).name()
```

Basically I want the size of the main window at all times, no matter which other windows are loaded on top of it. I've only found `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect` which both do the same thing, just wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: The issue is really your problem statement. Windows does not maintain the notion of a *"main window"*. Any Windows program can have zero or more top-level windows. Unless you produce a succinct specification of what you really need, you aren't going to solve this.

Comment: Having not developed for windows I don't know what's possible and isn't, but I would have thought dialogue boxes and the menu dropdowns would be parented to the main window. Generally when I've seen multiple windows from the same program, each is running as a separate process, which is fine. I just kinda need the main parent window of the selected process if it exists.

Comment: I actually figured it out from that comment haha, searching for parents appears to have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get to the solution by realising it was basically the last parent window I needed:

```
def _get_parent(self):
    while True:
        try:
            parent = win32gui.GetParent(hwnd)
        except UnboundLocalError:
            hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        else:
            if parent:
                hwnd = parent
            else:
                break
    return hwnd
```

Basically it just keeps checking if the current window has a parent until there are no more parents. Not super efficient but does the job. I've only really tested it on `paint > save as > are you sure you want to replace?`, but it gets the correct `hwnd` value for the main window and returns a constant resolution.